# Why does my javascript stop working when hosted?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, scripting, hosting

When the html file is ran it works great! When I upload it to my dreamhost domain, the buttons cease to work, and the initially hidden tags are suddenly visible. I have this same issue on another page, the jquery seems to just stop working when I actually host my files. div "rainDesc" and the h3 under are supposed to fade in.

I am using bootstrap and animejs.

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Relax...</title>
        <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="rainContent">
            <video id="rainVideo" src="Rain falling on windshield.mp4"></video>
        </div>
        <div class="greeting">
            <h1 class="display-2">Let's create the mood...</h1>
            <small class="text-muted">Just relax</small>
        </div>
        <div class="rainDesc">
            <h3>You're in a warm car, the gentle rain falling on the windshield is soothing...</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="medType">
            <button id="rain" type="button" class="btn btn-light">Rain</button>
            <button id="zen" type="button" class="btn btn-light">Zen</button>
            <button id="sun" type="button" class="btn btn-light">Sun</button>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js" integrity="sha512-z4OUqw38qNLpn1libAN9BsoDx6nbNFio5lA6CuTp9NlK83b89hgyCVq+N5FdBJptINztxn1Z3SaKSKUS5UP60Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="app.js" text="script"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
var greeting = document.querySelector('.greeting')
var rainDesc = document.querySelector('.rainDesc')

window.onload = function(){
    Rainvideo.style.display = 'none'
    rainDesc.style.display = 'none'
    anime({
        targets: Rainvideo,
        opacity: 0
    })
    anime({
        targets: rainDesc,
        opacity: 0
    })
}

document.getElementById("rain").onclick = function(){

    Rainvideo.style.display = 'block'
    Rainvideo.play();
    Rainvideo.loop = true;
    rainDesc.style.display = 'block' 

    anime({
        targets: Rainvideo,
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 10000
    })

    anime({
        targets: rainDesc,
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 10000
    })

    anime({
        targets: greeting,
        translateY: -150,
        duration: 5000
    })
}
```

I took the jquery out, but still it does not seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any error messages in the console?

Comment: Try putting the script tags on header part the ones that are for required js libraries. Keep the app.js below but move others to head.

Comment: Where is defined `Rainvideo` ?

Comment: error message Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'. Says it's on line 42, the last line. Even more confusing because the brackets all check out

Comment: Rainvideo is in the folder

Comment: Instead of `text="script"` try `type="text/javascript"`, or just remove it altogether.

Comment: Okay guys, so when I open up my browser, my javascript is being repeated 3 times in the console, causing an error. Any insight into why it's repeating?